# Python Reddit API: Extracting User Comments Between Two Given Timestamps

Tags: reddit, praw

PRAW allows extracting `submissions` on a given subreddit between two timestamps using this:
`reddit.subreddit('news').submissions(startStamp, endStamp)`

However, I haven't been able to find anything similar for extracting a given user's comments between two timestamps. Can this be done? I don't actually care about the 1000-requests limit unless the comments I get belong to the correct time range. I already had a look at their documentation [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering referring to [Pushshift](https://www.reddit.com/r/pushshift/). You can get the comments by a user (let's say `/u/avi8tr`) at the following URL: [Link](https://apiv2.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?author=Av8tir&before=1514174340&after=1514174330) .

There's a python wrapper (just like PRAW) for Pushshift as well, but it's under development: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/teaearlgraycold/psraw). You'll have to add the `'author'` parameter in comment_search in `psraw/endpoints.py`, though.

Note: Both Pushshift and PSRAW are begin developed actively. So changes are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no argument for it like there is for the `.submissions`call, you can do this manually with an `if` statement checking the `created_utc` against another utc timestamp. (You can use something like https://www.epochconverter.com/ to get a desired timestamp)

The following code sample gets all of /u/spez's comments from last christmas to this christmas.

```
import praw
oldest = 1482682380.0 #Timestamp for 12/25/16
newest = 1514218380.0 #Timestamp for 12/25/17
reddit = praw.Reddit('USER-AGENT-HERE')
for comment in reddit.redditor('spez').comments.new(limit= None):
    if comment.created_utc > oldest and comment.created_utc < newest:
        print "Comment Found! permalink: " + comment.permalink
```

Comment: This fails when the user has made more than 1000 comments in the given timeframe. Moreover, since you're getting the comments before checking if they lie in the given timeframe; there are some comments that you'll never be able to extract. Just  a word of caution for those who are going to use this in future.

Comment: Since he's using Python, its easier to convert `.created_utc` using

`datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1482682380.0)` to return a datetime instance `datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 25, 16, 13)`